# SELECT on same table AFTER INSERT TRIGGER fails?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, database-trigger

I am writing a small AFTER INSERT trigger being executed after insert of a row in a table A.
So simplified we´ve got these three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE A (Id INTEGER, datum DATE, ...);
CREATE TABLE B (Id INTEGER, ...);
CREATE TABLE C (Id INTEGER, Aref INTEGER, Bref INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(Aref) REFERENCES A(Id), FOREIGN KEY(Bref) REFERENCES B(Id));
```

So now the tricky thing is, that the rows out of table B should only be selected, if they are EITHER not referenced at all in table C OR, if they are referenced in table C, the datum field in the row of A also being referenced in this row of C IS NOT NULL.
You´re getting it?
So I tried my luck with a select clause looking the following:

```
SELECT * FROM B b WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT c.* FROM C c, A a WHERE c.Bref = b.Id AND c.Aref = A.Id and a.datum IS NULL);
```

So now the trigger is throwing an exception, because "the table is modified at the moment and the trigger could probably not see it" cited the error message. But I need the information of table A and I need it to be an AFTER INSERT Trigger cause the same trigger is using this rows for a calculation itself inserting rows in a table D with reference to this row of A. 
So now the question is, how is it possible to select this rows of A after insert and make sure it keeps consistent?

Comment: Why do you need to select *this* row of A; if your trigger is for each row then you can use [the `:NEW` pseudorecord](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-4CF74E99-8859-4AB1-96E7-07898A2ABB9E)?

Comment: I need to check all rows of A, that´s the problem. And I don´t know how to exclude this row of the select. Would it work in that case?

Comment: There [quite a few questions about this sort of problem](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+trigger+mutating); you might find some inspiration there, e.g. with a compound trigger. A trigger may not be the correct tool at all; you might want a procedure that does the A insert and then takes further actions. I don't really understand your specific requirements enough to be more specific I'm afraid.